# Return value from node js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am using a node npm module in a next js app to get data from an api.

```
static async getInitialProps() {
    const zxapi = new Zxapi(connectId, secretKey);
    const res2 = await zxapi.programs({ region: "DE" }, function(err, result) {
        if (err != null) {
            return err
        }
        console.log(result, "before return");
        return result
        console.log(result, "after return");
    });
    return { res2 };
}
```

I need to return the values of `res2`. The "before return" `console.log` logs the data to the terminal and terminates there. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: can you ```console.log(res2)``` just before ```return {
  res2
};``` and see if it gets there?

Comment: `return result` is probably returning the data.

Comment: @ifiok nope, it doesnt

Comment: @AbdullahKhan its not :( iv checked

Comment: `await` only works with functions that return a promise.  It does not appear that `zxapi.programs()` returns a promise (because you're using a plain callback with it, not a promise).  For a discussion of the options for returning values form an asynchronous function, see this very popular answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/816620

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

Can you check if `zxapi.programs` returns a `Promise`? If it doesn't, you might have to create a function that makes it return a `Promise`.

For example, you can use something like

```
function zxpromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => zxapi.programs({ region: "DE" }, function(err, result) {
        if (err != null) {
            reject(err);
        }
        console.log(result, "before return");
        resolve(result);
        console.log(result, "after return");
    }));
}
```

and then, you can call zxpromise as

```
const res2 = await zxpromise()
```